# How to proceed to enlarge /boot

Tags: ubuntu, partition, luks, gparted, move-partition

I know how to use gparted on a livecd to resize partitions, but here it's a bit more complex and I don't want to screw it up. I have a `/boot` which is ridiculously small (can hold only one kernel at a time, so it's very contrived to upgrade). Here's the setup:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000f146d
Device     Boot  Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048     499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 1000214527 999712770 476.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 1000214527 999712768 476.7G 83 Linux

$ lsblk -f
NAME                     FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                                       
├─sda1                   ext2        1.0            25830e25-c61f-466b-9239-ced150ccf577       58M    70% /boot
├─sda2                                                                                                    
└─sda5                   crypto_LUKS 1              3102b8d0-a320-49db-b764-1a23c495ab20                  
└─sda5_crypt           LVM2_member LVM2 001       WJjfMf-xUhh-2iob-ow9v-RWfN-TG9L-cc3GOz                
    ├─kubuntu--vg-root   ext4        1.0            003987e7-8317-4cd2-b47b-561378ea0245       52G    84% /
    └─kubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap        1              3e69be10-8e23-4460-a16f-74ffef8fe290                  [SWAP]
```

Seems to me, before I can enlarge `/dev/sda1`, I need to shrink `/dev/sda2` (or is that `/dev/sda5` ?), move it forward and then enlarge `/dev/sda1`. But since `/dev/sda2/5` is an encrypted partition holding the system, maybe I need to do extra things to `/dev/sda5(_crypt)` ?!?

As you can tell, I don't have a clear understanding of the relationship between `sda2`, `sda5` and `sda5_crypt`. Note that those are listed here as seen from the booted system, not from the liveCD.

Comment: I do not know LVM, but you have the old MBR partitions. So sda2 is an extended partition and sda5 is fully using it. And then your LVM volumes fully use sda5. Now much better to use gpt, but that may erase drive, so you only want to convert when doing major reinstall or new drive. Your 243MB is not real small for /boot. Have you housecleaned it? http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Comment: What do you mean, 'not really small' ? `5.11.0-18-generic` takes 137Mb in `/boot`, so there's no space for another kernel...

Answer (score 0):

First, /boot is not *too* small. It is small enough to be uncomfortable, but since a typical ubuntu kernel is maybe 12MB, initrd 55MB + some config files, you should have space for two, if not three different kernels. What else is there?

And, if you really need/want bigger /boot, I'd suggest reusing the swap partition - you'll have to shrink the encrypted vlume, though. Unless you need hibernation.

If you have an external 1TB or so USB drive, I'd suggest making a (verbatim) copy of your disk there and experiment only after that.

Comment: Like stated, the latest kernel takes up 137Mb, so more than half. And look at the lsblk output: reusing swap is not possible as it is part of the encrypted partition, part of the sda5, part of sda2.