# How to upgrade with kernel taking more than half of /boot

Tags: kernel, boot, grub, upgrade

The latest Linux kernel now takes more than half of my `/boot` space. Next time I want to upgrade, how do I do that? Can I purge the current in-use kernel and then issue `aptitude full-upgrade` or `do-release-upgrade`? Seems dangerous and with possible side effects (loss of config?)

```
$ df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       236M  166M   58M  75% /boot
$ du -hc /boot/*5.11.0-18*
249K    /boot/config-5.11.0-18-generic
117M    /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-18-generic
5.8M    /boot/System.map-5.11.0-18-generic
15M     /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-18-generic
137M    total
```

Or is the only solution to boot from liveCD, chroot into your system, delete the current kernel and install the new one ?

Comment: My install of impish has initrd.img-5.11.0-18-generic at 87.2MB. Where are you getting your oversize version. Includes some testing data?

Comment: You will have to extend your `/boot` partition because it will be painful each time you want to install a new kernel. Also, your `initrd` is unusally large as if it includes a lot more drivers or boot scripts than necessary.

Comment: I asked about extending /boot in another thread (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654214/how-to-proceed-to-enlarge-boot/654218) but it just looks too risky and complex. As for shrinking the kernel by removing unused drivers, I know how to do that manually by editing `.config` (I program embedded systems) but I have no idea how to do it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to halve the size taken by the initrd and associated files by simply changing `MODULES=most` to `MODULES=dep` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`

I left the compression unchanged as it was already using lz4 which, I believe, is currently the better compression ratio.

Then run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` to have it take effect, and reboot to test.